# Connecting to GoogleCalendar using Android

Tags: android, authentication, httprequest, oauth-2.0, google-calendar-api

I'm currently trying to connect my android app with some calendar from the GoogleCalendar.

But I'm totally confused on how to authenticate the calls.
I do understand I have to do this with OAuth2.0

But there is no clear example or tutorial I can follow/understand right.
I tried following the following steps described out here:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

But I keep getting confused at probably the very basics.

My question is this. Can anyone help me understand the following steps and perhaps provide some example code?

Step 1: Request the OAuth2.0 token.

Step 2: Validate the OAuth2.0 token and retrieve the accessToken

Step 3: Use the accessToken and actually do the HTTPRequest call that gives me the JSON I so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Is your question up to date or did you solved your problem already?

Edit:

Here a little Basic info how to implement the GoogleCalendar:

1.Create a Class to handle a calendar :

```
public class MyCalendar
{
  private static final String   AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE = "cl";
  public static final String KEY = "YOUR_API_KEY";  //You can find below Simple API Access at GoogleApiConsole
  final HttpTransport   transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
  final JsonFactory factory = new GsonFactory();
  GoogleAccountManager accountManager;
  String name;
  String token;
  public com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar mycalendar;

  private HttpRequestInitializer initializer = new HttpRequestInitializer() 
  {
     public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException
     {           
        request.getHeaders().setAuthorization(GoogleHeaders.getGoogleLoginValue(authToken));
     }
  };

  public MyCalendar()
  {
  }
}
```

1. Create an Calendar object (I do this into MyCalendar's constructor

   ```
   mycalendar = com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.builder(transport,jsonFactory)
                 .setApplicationName("CHOOSE_A_APPNAME")                      
                 .setHttpRequestInitializer(initializer)
                 .setJsonHttpRequestInitializer(new GoogleKeyInitializer(KEY))
                 .build();
   accountManager = new GoogleAccountManager(TimetableApplication.getInstance().getActivity());
   findGoogleAcc();
   ```

The initializer's initialize method [;-)] will call later, if u want to acces your calendar.

2.Search for GoogleAccount refered to user's phone

```
void findGoogleAcc()
{
    Account account = accountManager.getAccountByName(name);
    if(account == null)
    {
        //Handle wrong name, or if user connect more than one accounts to phone
    }
    if(token != null)
    {
        //you already got your token for user's account and these method is not necessary
    }
    accountManager.getAccountManager().getAuthToken(account, AUTH_TOKEN_TYPE, true, new AccountManagerCallback<Bundle>() {

        public void run(AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> future)
        {
            try
            {
                Bundle bundle = future.getResult();
                if(bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT))
                {
                    // Allow app to connect to googleaccount
                    Intent intent = bundle.getParcelable(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT);
                    intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() & ~ Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    activity.startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                }
                else
                    if(bundle.containsKey(AccountManager.KEY_AUTHTOKEN))
                    {
                        this.authToken = authToken;
                        gotSmthFromCalendar();
                    }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
            }
        }
    }, null);
}
```

3.Use your calendar on Method :

```
     void gotSmthFromCalendar()
     {
         //Here u can do whatever u want.
     }
```

I think on gotSmthFromCalendar() you should use an AsyncTask to requezst data. for example you can do :

```
   List<CalendarListEntry> calendarList = mycalendar.calendarList().list().execute().getItems();
   for(CalendarListEntry calendarEntry : calendarList)
   {
        String summary = calendarEntry.getSummary();
        String id = calendarEntry.getId();
        Log.v("Calendar","Found a calendar with summary : " + summary + " an id: " + id);
   }
```

Hope these basics can help you to use v3. If u need additional help ask me everytime!!

Kooki

Comment: Not answered, but fixed in our project by using google cal v1 instead of v3

Comment: ahh ok, but remember that v1 is obsolete.if you need help i might can help you a little bit.Here some basics: You haveto create a GoogleApi (https://code.google.com/apis/console) and create a project over there.you also have to add all required librarys to your project.after that u can simply create an Calendarobject with a static builder. did u already have this?

Comment: Yup. Unfortunately there were still some issues with these things, there is no decent tutorial or example explaining the exact steps you have to do to be sure of a oauth2.0-authentication. I know v1 is obsolete but for this it worked and there is probably no time to fix it properly. But a good solution for the next case is always welcome.